# get string from outside run programm

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have jsp page with text field and button. Also i have jar of another project.
When i click on the button the MAIN.class of the jar is called and program is running in independent window(JFrame).
After user is finished with the program and exits, I need to get the String of program that is generated on exit and paste it into the textbox (The String is HTML code)

Is anyone else having this problem and has a solution?
Thanks
Alex

Comment: your question is not clear to me, can you please elaborate  `I need to get the String of program that is generated on exit and paste it into the textbox (The String is HTML code)`

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between launching an application on the server machine versus launching an application on the client machine.  Your question suggests you might have some confusion.  As to doing things on the client side, it is probably better to do the part that produces the HTML in an applet or JWS launched frame.  Either of these can directly communicate with the server and then the HTML form becomes redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "jar from another project" prints its output to standart output. You can use below code to take output in your servlet.

```
          try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
                Process pr = rt.exec("{EXTERNAL_JAR_EXECUTE_COMMAND}");

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                String line=null;

                while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                int exitVal = pr.waitFor();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Great it works! But how to send String to the Buffer on exit from JFRAME? I tried to write to a buffer but nothing happens, the code is stay in the while loop? Thanks

Comment: How does it stay? The code stay until read lines finished. In my opinion close this question and ask your question in a new question with your code so We may help you according to your code.

Comment: OK i figure out:
ByteBuffer bb= ByteBuffer.wrap(out.getBytes()); 
where out is my String
But your code is waiting for readline()=null!
I`ve tried sent null to BUFFER but nothing happens. So how i end this loop? Thanks

Comment: Maybe waiting the end of the program or closing the connection. Alternatively you can send your own end-loop string to break loop

Answer (score 0):

This ain't ever going to work in a production environment. Java code is executed at webserver (server side) and HTML code is executed at webbrowser (client side). Basically, that Swing thing would only be executed at the webserver, not at the webbrowser. It would only work when both the webserver and webbrowser runs by coincidence at physically the same machine (like as when you're developing locally).

Wrap it in an [Applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) which communicates to a HTTP servlet or just transform the Swing thing to HTML so that you don't need to hassle with that.